# throw exception Java 8 Lambda

Tags: java, lambda, option-type

I have a service which look up record from DB and returns an optional record, then depends on the record is present or not I need to push the record message to kafka, and here is my code:

```
public void process(final String message) throws ProcessorError {
    Optional<User> saved = userService.save(message);    
    saved.ifPresent(theUser -> kafkaProducer.produce(message));
  }
```

however kafkaProducer could throw an EncryptionError which is a subclass of ProcessorError, so the IntelliJ is not happy about it. as it suggested i had to change the code to this:

```
saved.ifPresent(
        theUser ->
        {
          try {
            kafkaProducer.produce(message);
          } catch (EncryptionError encryptionError) {
            encryptionError.printStackTrace();
          }
        });
```

but i don't want to print stacktrace at this point, instead i just want to re-throw it, so i change it again to this:

```
saved.ifPresent(
        theUser ->
        {
          try {
            kafkaProducer.produce(message);
          } catch (EncryptionError encryptionError) {
            throw encryptionError;
          }
        });
```

yet IntelliJ is unhappy again , suggested me to surround that throw statement with another try/catch, how can i just throw it without annoying compiler?

Thanks everyone for replying, but I do need to keep it as EncryptionError not RuntimeException and I don't like to surrounding throw encryptionError with another try/catch, do i go back to old way :

```
if (saved.isPresent()) {
   kafkaProducer.produce(message);
}
```

Comment: You need to tell Java that the method can throw and EncryptionError. You do that when you define the method, such as "public void xxx throws EncryptionError".

Comment: A work-around that is ugly: in the try/catch block in the lamba, save the exception then throw an unchecked Exception that if specific to you. Surround the "saved" function with a try/catch to catch the unchecked exception and throw saved EncryptionError.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen [I beg to differ](https://pastebin.com/zD26SRkq)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming EncryptionError is a checked exception, you can just wrap it in an unchecked exception.

```java
saved.ifPresent(
        theUser ->
        {
          try {
            kafkaProducer.produce(message);
          } catch (EncryptionError encryptionError) {
            throw new RuntimeException(encryptionError);
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that EncryptionError is a subtype of checked exception. So just wrap it with RuntimeException and you are done. Like this:
`try {
        ....
    } catch (EncryptionError e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }`

Comment: Better throw `new RuntimeException(e)` to keep the stack trace.

Comment: Even better to include debug information in the message for the wrapped exception too

Answer (score 0):

1. As already was mentioned, wrapping checked exception to unchecked one is the way to go, you don't need to declare it in the signature method anymore.
2. Lambdas suppose to be short and clear. Proper encapsulation is the key to success.
3. Narrower exceptions types are your best friends. `throw MessageProducingException` is better than `throw RuntimeException`.

Summarizing what I worte above:

```
// Getting rid of throws signature
public void process(final String message) {
    userService.save(message)    
         .ifPresent(user -> produceMessage(message);
}

// encapsulated produce method, will deal with exception wrapping
private void produceMessage(Message message) {
     try {
        kafkaProducer.produce(message);
      } catch (EncryptionError encryptionError) {
        // creating and using custom domain-specic exception here, pick up a proper name
        throw new MessageProducingException(encryptionError);
      }
}
```

Further step for improvement could be to add another level of abstraction to your `kafkaProducer` and use more abstact `producer` instead.